# Online passes with Barcode

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I  have to set up a system for an online-pass generator using barcodes.

The module i developed lets the admins set which codes are available, and when a user requests a pass, the php script generates a jpeg of the pass with a small barcode print at the bottom.

The barcode is generated using:
http://www.dafont.com/3of9-barcode.font

Q: Are those barcodes universal? I need to know if the barcode scanner will work on those printed passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually quite a few different sets of barcode characters out there. You need to find out which standard the scanners that will be reading the codes will use and find a font or generator that supports that standard.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Symbologies for a list of them.

Answer (score 2):

mikeschuld has provided good information about barcode printing and scanning.  My experience has been that Code 39 is one of the most pervasive barcode formats and every scanner that I have run into has been configured to read Code 39 barcodes by default.